# Can not open session for facebook

Tags: android, android-facebook

I had make FBLogin demo using [this tutotial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/)

Code is here //MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // start Facebook Login
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            Log.v("log_tag", "Token=" + session.getAccessToken());
            Log.v("log_tag", "Token=" + session.isOpened());

            if (session.isOpened()) {

                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            // callback after Graph API response with user
                            // object
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                                    welcome.setText("Hello "
                                            + user.getName() + "!");
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}
}
```

//AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.fbdemo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.fbdemo.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

output in `log_cat` is like this

```
02-14 19:08:25.251: V/log_tag(1558): Token=
02-14 19:08:25.251: V/log_tag(1558): Token=false
02-14 19:08:38.834: V/log_tag(1558): Token=
02-14 19:08:38.834: V/log_tag(1558): Token=false
```

please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: download this example code http://www.sendspace.com/file/biqcnt

Comment: Voting to close as no-longer-repro since there's a deleted self-answer that says there was a problem with key hash.

Comment: Most problems can be solved by just using this nice abstraction: https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

Comment: This issue was awnsered on the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062095/facebook-android-sdk-does-not-open-session-after-login

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the hash key generated.Sometimes wrong key may be generated. So check the key and try again. The problem solved for me when I changed the key.