# Facebook Android SDK does not open Session after login

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

1) This question appears many times and the awnser is always "you have the wrong Key Hash".

2) Facebook documentation tells we to use this code to get our Key Hash:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MyKeyAlias -keystore path\to\my\Key | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

3) Ok, this gives me that key: 1yl**********Q3A

When I try to login, I got the following message:
    com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: (#404) Key hash XHA**********q10 does not match any stored key hashes.

4) Then I copy and paste the XHA**********q10 on my app settings and thats not my key either.

5) So, I read on documentation that was a code that gives you the correct Key Hash. This code:

```
// Add code to print out the key hash
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

It worked! Gave me this hash: +HA**********q0=

6) I put this last hash on app settings and YES, now I can connect! BUT, now I can't open a Session!!!

I'm using the following code:

```
public class FBActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_view);

        System.out.println("Start Facebook login");
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, 
                                              Exception exception) {
                System.out.println("Call");
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    System.out.println("Open");
                    Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                            System.out.println("Complete");
                            if (user != null) {
                                System.out.println(user.getName());

                            } else {
                                System.out.println("User NULL");
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
                } else {
                System.out.println("Not open");
            }

        });
    }
}
```

And the log is:

"Start Facebook Login

Call

Not open

Call

Not open"

I don't know what else can I do, since I already have the correct Key Hash and I can make the login.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out:

The following method was missing. Just added it and everything worked.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: OMG YOU SAVED OUR LIVES IN MY JUNIOR PROJECT, THANK YOU ALOTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT, THIS FUNCTION SOLVED IT THANK YOUUUUUUU

Answer (score 0):

Are making call again and again (By clicking same login button). If yes then facebook dialog will not open after 1st time (on fist time click of login bttn it will open fbk dialog but not after that)
Reason:  Because session is created and it is not cleared `ie person is not logged out with the help of this session you can get profile info of fbk user.

if you want to do that that can too be happen just write these lines of code:

```
 Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
             if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session is opened",
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             /* clear session and again click will show facebook login */

             session = Session.getActiveSession();
             if (!session.isClosed()) {
             session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
             }

             }
```

after clearing token now make login call

```
FacebookAuthentication();


    private void FacebookAuthentication() {

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // "new session was created and requires login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        // .show();

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        OpenRequest op = new Session.OpenRequest(SignUpActivity.this);

        op.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        op.setCallback(statusCallback);

        op.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));

        Session session = new Session.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        session.openForRead(op);

    }
```

Declare  globally

```
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();.
```

//private emails are not accessed

```
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(final Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {

                makeFacebookMeRequest(session);

            }

        }
    }

public void makeFacebookMeRequest(final Session session) {

        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                if (user != null) {

                    String access_token = session.getAccessToken();

                    Log.d("Response", "Response=" + response);
                    Log.d("AccessToken", access_token);

                    UserId_FromFacebook = user.getId();
                    UserName_FromFacebook = user.getUsername();
                    FirstName_FromFacebook = user.getFirstName();
                    LastName_FromFacebook = user.getLastName();

                    try {

                        Email_FromFacebook = user.asMap().get("email")
                                .toString();

                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        // "" + Email_FromFacebook, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        // .show();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        // e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

                //You can move to your activiy here and make sure user is signed up using your api

            }

        }).executeAsync();
    }
```

//////////////////Apply this patch in your code :)  Call below method for login and it will solve your problems   (if on same button click again and again you want fbk dialog just uncomment my code in below method )//////////////////////

```
private void LoginAndFetchFacebookProfileInfo() {

        Session currentSession = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (currentSession == null || currentSession.getState().isClosed()) {



            Session session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
            Session.setActiveSession(session);

            currentSession = session;

        }

        if (currentSession.isOpened()) {

//you are logged in so do whatever you want
            // Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "session is  opened",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            makeFacebookMeRequest(currentSession);

            // Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
            // if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            //
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "session is opened",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //
            // /* clear session and again click will show facebook login */
            //
            // session = Session.getActiveSession();
            // if (!session.isClosed()) {
            // session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            // }
            //
            // }
            //
            // FacebookAuthentication();

        } else if (!currentSession.isOpened()) {
            // Ask for username and password
            // Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "session is not opened",
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            FacebookAuthentication();
        }

    }
```